# seeking example of azure Linux VM deprovisioning itself (via helper VM)

Tags: azure

I would not imagine that a VM could deprovision itself fully (but that would be a nice feature), but must start a helper VM to do that. I am seeking an example of such for a Linux VM. I would actually like an example where a VM could be completely cleaned up after, deprovision, delete, delete disks (boot included), no trace left, no storage consumed, nada.

Comment: You mean a VM calls some function to delete itself? - It could call the powershell 'Remove-AzureVM' command against itself (or other platform alternatives)

Comment: I am thinking that command won't complete, because the first thing it will do is stop the VM. In any case, I'm looking for total cleanup and Linux specific (edited question to reflect this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running from Linux you can use the [Azure CLI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/) which provides the functionality you need.

If you run a force delete on a VM with the option to delete the underlying disk, the command will be registered with Azure before the operation starts, therefore it is perfectly possible to completely delete a running VM from within that VM.

Since you're deleting the entire stack, there's no need to gracefully shutdown beforehand (which would be more challenging - though not impossible) You can just hit the delete button and let Azure figure the rest out.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do it, however, I don't see any force option. This is what I did: `$ azure vm delete -b -q  kjb05fastjobs1p0
info:    Executing command vm delete
+ Getting virtual machines
warn:    No VMs found
info:    vm delete command OK`  . I did this from my local machine, not trying to kill a machine from itself. All that happened is the machine was stopped. It is still provisioned and the boot disk is still attached.

Comment: However, it does work when it is run from itself with the "-q" omitted. I just have to do a here document or some such thing to answer the prompt with "yes". Why it works for suicide but not homicide is beyond me.

Comment: Ok, without the -q, homicide works too. Here is the code (windows & linux shell scripts):  echo yes|azure vm delete -b my-vm-name .  One issue that I have is that this will delete the cloud service too. I would like to keep an active cloud service around and have VMs come and go on that service. I don't know what happens with multiple VMs in a cloud service when one of them commits suicide - do they all die because their cloud service goes away?

Comment: This shouldn't delete your service at all! You'd need the 'service delete' command for that.

Comment: When it is the last VM running in the service, it deletes it.